# How can I convert all the labels in my program to procedures?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG
;---------------------
; your variables here
;---------------------

    number      db  169d    




    prompt      db  13d,10d,'Please enter a valid number : $'
    lessMsg     db  13d,10d,'Value if Less ','$'
    moreMsg     db 13d,10d,'Value is More ', '$'
    equalMsg    db 13d,10d,'You have made fine Guess!', '$'
    overflowMsg db  13d,10d,'Error - Number out of range!', '$'
    retry       db  13d,10d,'Retry [y/n] ? ' ,'$'

    guess       db  0d    
    errorChk    db  0d      




CODESEG
start:
     mov ax,@data
     mov ds, ax
;---------------------
;your code here  
;---------------------


    MOV ax, 0h
    MOV bx, 0h
    MOV cx, 0h
    MOV dx, 0h

    MOV BX, OFFSET guess   
    MOV [BX], 0d   

    MOV BX, OFFSET errorChk 
    MOV [BX], 0d   


    MOV ax, @data           
    MOV ds, ax             
    MOV dx, offset prompt  

    MOV ah, 9h             
    INT 21h                

    MOV cl, 0h             
    MOV dx, 0h             
whil:

    CMP     cl, 5d          
    JG      endwhile       

    MOV     ah, 1h          
    INT     21h             

    CMP     al, 0Dh         
    JE      endwhile        

    SUB     al, 30h        
    MOV     dl, al        
    PUSH    dx              
    INC     cl             

    JMP whil           

endwhile:

    DEC cl                

    CMP cl, 02h           
    JG  overflow            

    MOV BX, OFFSET errorChk 
    MOV  [BX], cl   

    MOV cl, 0h            

while2:

    CMP cl,errorChk
    JG endwhile2

    POP dx                  

    MOV ch, 0h             
    MOV al, 1d              
    MOV dh, 10d             


 while3:

    CMP ch, cl              
    JGE endwhile3          

    MUL dh                  

    INC ch                 
    JMP while3

 endwhile3:




    MUL dl                  

    JO  overflow            

    MOV dl, al             
    ADD dl, guess          

    JC  overflow            

    MOV BX, OFFSET guess    
    MOV  [BX], dl   

    INC cl                

    JMP while2              

endwhile2:


    MOV ax, @data          
    MOV ds, ax              

    MOV dl, number         
    MOV dh, guess           

    CMP dh, dl              

    JC greater              
    JE equal               
    JG lower                
equal:

    MOV dx, offset equalMsg 
    MOV ah, 9h             
    INT 21h                 
    JMP exit               

greater:

    MOV dx, offset moreMsg  
    MOV ah, 9h              
    INT 21h               
    JMP start              

lower:

    MOV dx, offset lessMsg  
    MOV ah, 9h             
    INT 21h                 
    JMP start              

overflow:

    MOV dx, offset overflowMsg
    MOV ah, 9h              
    INT 21h                
    JMP start              
exit:


retry_while:

    MOV dx, offset retry    

    MOV ah, 9h              
    INT 21h                 

    MOV ah, 1h             
    INT 21h                 

    CMP al, 6Eh             
    JE return_to_DOS        

    CMP al, 79h             
    JE restart             


    JMP retry_while         



restart:

    JMP start               
return_to_DOS:

     mov ax,4c00h
     int 21h
     end start
```

**the labels which I talk about are:whil,endwhile,while2,endwhile3,while3,endwhile2,equal, greater, lower, overflow,retry_while,**

Comment: That's quite the code dump, and what do you mean exactly by converting to a procedure?

Comment: You'll have to restructure the flow logic if you break your code into procedures, because of the branches and jumps to other places. Assuming your code works, first pick *one* small section and write a procedure to do the job. Then call the procedure instead of running the in-line code. Step by step. Perhaps consider returning a value from the more complicated procedures, to tell the calling code what to do next.

Comment: I did not read all of the code, but it looks as if most of these labels are there to make loops and some to implement if-like statements. Why would you want to turn them into procedures? You can refactor your code to use procedures, but most of these labels seem to be needed anyway, because you will still have to loop or branch.

Comment: You could turn the system calls (e.g. INT 21h calls and the code around them) into separate procedures and call these. But the labels would still be needed.